# MySQL NDB Cluster Database Row locking in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, locking, cluster-computing

I am trying to implement database row locking in a MqSQL NDB cluster but was not able to do it. I am trying to implement locking in the `transfer` method.

1. How can I implement mysql cluster row locking? I have read http://lists.mysql.com/cluster/5533  and wasnt able to find any tutorial or help on how to do it.
2. And how do I ensure the locks are consistent across all the data nodes?

.

```
public double getBal(String userid) throws SQLException { 
    Statement stmt = db.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select balance from account where id='"+userid+"'");

    return balance;
}
```

Transfer method

```
public boolean transfer(String useridFrom, String useridTo, double amount) throws SQLException {


    //perform validation
    //have to lock the table here.
    double fromBal = getBal(useridFrom);
    double newBal = fromBal - amount;

    // transfer fund
    Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
    try {
        s.execute("set autocommit=0");
        s.execute("START TRANSACTION");
        s.executeUpdate("UPDATE account SET balance=" + newBal + " WHERE id='" + useridFrom+ "' ");

        double toBal = getBalance(useridTo);
        double newBalTo = toBal + amount;
        s.executeUpdate("UPDATE accounts SET balance=" + newBalTo + " WHERE id='" + useridTo+ "' ");

        s.execute("commit");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        s.execute("rollback");
    }
    return true;
}
```